# Context menu paste in textbox not updated binding element value

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-5.0, silverlight-toolkit

I'm binding a text box to a textblock, but it is not updated when I paste something using the context menu.

Following there is the XAML code for element binding:

```
<uc:CustomTextBox x:Name="txtBoxLastName"
                  Grid.Row="3"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  Width="80"
                  Height="25"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" />

<TextBlock Grid.Row="4"
           Grid.Column="1"
           Width="100"
           Height="100"
           Text="{Binding Text,
                          ElementName=txtBoxLastName}" />
```

Context menu paste code:

```
this.SelectedText = Clipboard.GetText();
```

What's wrong with this code? Is there any other way to do the same ?

Regards.

Comment: But it is calling text change but not updating the element binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the common Silverlight controls, the text pasted in the TextBox control is automatically pasted also in the TextBlock control.

I think the problem is in the code you're using to paste the text stored in the Clipboard, because you're setting the property `SelectedText`, when instead your TextBlock's `Text` property is bound to the `Text` property of the TextBox.

You can change the line from:

```
this.SelectedText = Clipboard.GetText();
```

to:

```
this.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
```

or, as second option, change the binding in your textblock from this:

```
Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=txtBoxLastName}"
```

to this:

```
Text="{Binding SelectedText, ElementName=txtBoxLastName}"
```

Comment: I don't want to replace the text, I'm updating text in the existing using paste.So I can't use Text instead of SelectedText